# How can I refresh a Panel from another ListView in Apache Wicket?

Tags: wicket

I have a panel (say `AlertPanel`) which needs to be refreshed for some condition when a listView renders.

I am thinking to update the `AlertPanel` in `onBeforeRender()` lifecycle method of listview.

**I have tried to override onBeforeRender() like this-**

```
            @Override
            protected void onBeforeRender() {
                super.onBeforeRender();
                // update alert panel with some API of Component here
                // I can get panel object like this 'this.getPage().get("alertPanel");'
            }
```

Once I have `this.getPage().get("alertPanel")`, I don't know what API of `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel` to call so that I can refresh/repaint `AlertPanel`

Comment: Use `replace` component will work for you .Check this link https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/componentLifecycle.html . But still i'm still not happy with the way you are calling the `AlertPanel`

Comment: Thanks for reply, however would you please put everything in one comment as it then becomes difficult to refer. Also, please specify reason as to why referring Panel in my way is not good

Comment: @soorapadman What is the problem with this way? Please suggest a better and a replace is not available to `this.getPage().get("alertPanel")` as it returns a `Component`. I can cast it but I don't think I should as Component already has `replaceWith()` which I have tried but does not work.

Comment: Honestly with this code i cannot sorted out this issue . Please update your like where you are adding the `panel(AlertPanel)` how you tried replace?

Comment: Please check with `martin-g `answer . But still im not sure that is what you are trying to do

Comment: The intention is clear from the question @soorapadman! Please state what you don't get? I have to refresh a component (say A) in wicket from another (say B) and preferably `onBeforeRender()` of component B

Comment: if you wanted to refresh panel you can simply do `target.add(alertPanel)` any of `click or submit` event ..but 'im not sure why you need to `onbefore render` . I thought you are trying to replacing the component with some other (As you mean update )

Answer (score 1):

If the rendering has started (and it seems it has - onBeforeRender()) then you won't be able to replace any components.

You should move your logic to the ACTION phase, e.g. onClick(), onSubmit(), etc. In such action method broadcast an event: `send(getPage(), Broadcast.DEPTH, new SomeCustomEvent())`. Then either in the AlertPanel's parent you should override #onEvent(IEvent) and when the event payload is `SomeCustomEvent` then do the replacement.

For more info read: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_wicket_events_infrastructure

Comment: You are correct in one way . if the component is same page why we need to use `broadcast`  event ?. `target.add(alertPanel)` enough right? forgive me if im wrong.

Comment: If you have a reference between the components then you do not need events. But quite often the Page is constructed with separate components/containers which know nothing about each other. To avoid tight coupling I'd recommend to communicate via messages, i.e. events.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:
1) the complex one: use listeners
2) or use method overriding, like this:

```
AlertPanel alertPanel = new AlertPanel();
alertPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);

ListView list = new MyListView(){
     @Override
     protected onMyEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target){
         target.add(alertPanel);
     }
}

page.add(alertPanel,list);
```

onMyEvent() method of MyListView can be abstract and have to be called where you want to update the alertPanel inside of MyListView (e.g. when button pressed in some of rows)